# Intellij IDEA is rebuilding a project after update

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij IDEA is rebuilding my project after running it. Every changes (even moving between windows) are reloading project, how to disable it? (Intellij IDEA last version, MacOS)

I tried a lot of and not found the answer. I have that problem after update

Comment: Do you have any "on save" actions configured in "Settings | Tools | Actions on Save"? Do you use any plugins or external tool that might modify code?

Comment: Also, please check if you have "On frame deactivation" selected under `Run | Edit Configurations... | your configuration | Update classes and resources`

Comment: If the problem remains contact JetBrains support team at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new